# Querying google maps for time between A & B

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

how do I query google maps to tell me how much time it takes to reach from point A to point B? I want to build an app which alerts me what's the right time to leave from office to home. I don't want to check every 5 minutes how the traffic pattern is.

Comment: do you have a business-license?

Comment: no. looks like I would need one? I read the documentation and it says I should not be using google result if I am not showing the maps to the user.

Comment: That restriction is another issue, but without a business-license it's not possible to retrieve durations that involve the current traffic-situation.